# Which actions or events will cause the game to auto-save?

Tags: state-of-decay

The Steam Early Access version* that I have doesn't allow manual saving, and only allows automatic saving. Due to that, it would be nice to know what actions or events will cause the game to auto-save.

**What actions or events will trigger an auto-save?**

---

<sup>* I'm making this question platform-agnostic. Answers for both the Xbox 360 and PC versions are welcome. If possible, please specify on which platform(s) your answer is about. Also, see this question's comments.</sup>

Comment: I'm not sure if the PC version of the game auto-saves in the same way as the Xbox 360 version. I'm playing the (PC) Steam Early Access version only. Let me know if they are different so I can tag this question with [PC] (or you could suggest an edit).

Comment: @CyberSkull RE: [This edit](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/131706/2). I initially didn't tag this with a platform or an OS tag as the PC version might auto-save in the same way as the Xbox 360 version. If that's the case, then this is so that this question will apply to both versions, and to follow this [meta] post's tagging suggestions: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4638/platform-tags-are-useless. By that retag, are you confirming that Xbox 360 version doesn't auto-save in the same way as the PC version?

Comment: I added the [tag:windows] tag because it seemed to me like you are distinctly asking about the Windows version of the game. If that is not your intent, please edit your question to be platform agnostic. ;)

Comment: @CyberSkull I see. I reverted the retag. I only wrote about the PC version in the question because it's the only version I have played. Since I am not sure of the differences between the PC and the Xbox 360 version's auto-save mechanics, I'll just make this question platform-agnostic (until someone can confirm that the two versions have different auto-save mechanics). Hopefully, the comments I wrote will get someone to confirm/clarify or deny the differences between the two versions.

Comment: We don't tag with platform tags just because a game version is on a certain platform. Platform tags are only for when the problem is about the platform itself as well, e.g., crashes, controller issues, etc. See every Skyrim question, for example. (If they're so different that the platform most often matters, they get separate game tags.)

Comment: @sevensideddie Generally, when one mentions the platform they are using the game on it is often a specific question about that version of the game. If one does not mention the platform they are using then any reader can assume they mean all versions.

Comment: @sevensideddie TL;DR don't mention platform unless you mean the platform you are playing on.

Comment: @CyberSkull No, do mention platform as context for the question, just like any other helpful detail. Just don't tag the platform unless the platform is the problem too. Not everything in a question is worth a tag.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that after completing a mission, the game will save your progress. If you quit in the middle of a mission, its status is reset, but your health and inventory status will be saved.

Answer (score 1):

Further to the above, from playing the Xbox 360 version at least, the game also saves when

- Construction completes at your base
- You make a radio call to search for base materials (fuel, construction materials, food, medical)
- Establishing an outpost - plus setting up traps at an outpost

There may be more I've missed.

I always found it easiest when I wanted to save-quit to make a radio call for materials (you need influence to do this but not much)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other current answers, from [comments in the Reddit /r/StateOfDecay post, "Save system irritates the hell out of me"](http://www.reddit.com/r/StateOfDecay/comments/1n6eph/save_system_irritates_the_hell_out_of_me/):

> - Switching characters forces the game to save on the XBLA version.
> - I switch characters before I want to quit because it forces the game to save. I've done it since I got the game on PC and I've yet to have it not save.
> - From what I recall on the Xbox version, changing any item in Settings and choosing Save and Exit will actually save your game progress as well.